# how to get webpack to bundle node_modules for angular 1

Tags: angularjs, typescript, webpack, typescript-typings

I am about to move `angular 1 + typescript` project build setup `from gulp to webpack`, the only part I am stuck with is, how to `bundle node_modules js` file in proper sequence.

I was till now using bower for client side dependencies, and gulp has `wiredep` plugin which will look into `bower dependencies section + main section` to build the dependency order and get it to bundle it properly.

Now I understand that webpack philosophy is different, we should depend upload whatever is imported rather than any dependencies section as such.

so to get it to work I will need to do: move all dependencies from bower.json to package.json

currently as I am using typings, tsc considers the typings and gives me the output, I really don't need to write imports for bower packages as such.

So if i understand correctly, to get it work with webpack,

> a) I should get away with typings and then directly import the js
>    files inside all my ts files??
>
> As I understand, all the js modules from npm do work with modules, so does webpack really needs typings files?

OR

> b) I should write a separate vendor.ts, where I should maintain the
>    sequence of imports (for js and css) myself,
>
> but then that would be little painful to do (given I am used to wiredep handling it for me).
>
> But then this will allow me bundle the vendor files separately using chunks-plugin

OR

> c) is there any other standard way to handle this.

This is kinda pain point to move angular 1 from gulp to webpack.

Answer (score 1):

When you import a module from a TypeScript file that's going to be loaded by webpack, it'll get it's content from `node_modules` and bundle it into the output file.

#### index.ts

```
import * as angular from "angular";

const myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);

myApp.controller("MyController", function PhoneListController($scope) {
  $scope.phones = [
    {
      name: "Nexus S",
      snippet: "Fast just got faster with Nexus S."
    }, {
      name: "Motorola XOOM™ with Wi-Fi",
      snippet: "The Next, Next Generation tablet."
    }, {
      name: "MOTOROLA XOOM™",
      snippet: "The Next, Next Generation tablet."
    }
  ];
});
```

#### index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
  ...
  <script src="bundle.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="MyController">

  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="phone in phones">
      <span>{{phone.name}}</span>
      <p>{{phone.snippet}}</p>
    </li>
  </ul>

</body>
</html>
```

#### webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    entry: "./index.ts",
    output: {
        filename: "./bundle.js"
    },
    devtool: "source-map",
    resolve: {
        extensions: ["", ".webpack.js", ".web.js", ".ts", ".tsx", ".js"]
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.tsx?$/, loader: "ts-loader" }
        ],
        preLoaders: [
            { test: /\.js$/, loader: "source-map-loader" }
        ]
    }
};
```

Add `angular`, `@types/angular`, `ts-loader`, `source-map-loader`, `typescript` to your `packages.json` and run `webpack`.

It'll bundle everything inside a single file named `bundle.js` which will be used by your `index.html`.

Comment: but what about sequence of third party dependencies... how will webpack make sure to add `angular` before `angular-ui`, I am not sure if angular-ui source code will have relevant import statement

Comment: The order doesn't really matter here as everything is going to be bundled into a single file. Just import everything you need to use on each file.